# Remove/edit internet slang acronyms from posts?

Tags: discussion

Generally speaking the community consensus with regard to posts ending in "thanks" is to remove it.

What about other similar idioms like internet slang acronyms?

Such as: HTH

I saw this [in a first post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41216/absence-of-negative-feedback-vs-presence-of-positive-feedback/41218#41218) and I removed it.

My personal opinion is it is in the same class as "thanks", but I'm interested to see what the larger community thinks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Jon here. I hope you are well. It's a bit cloudy here, pity as it's supposed to be the summer solstice today, first day of summer and look what we get!

Anyway, you had a question so I'll do my best to answer you, hopefully it'll be something that will be of interest, if not then let me know and I'll see if I can change it. Only trying to be helpful and all.

so, my answer:

Anything that gets in the way of the answer is just noise that people have to get past in order to get to the useful content. It's fine to be friendly and polite, but that should come from guiding people to leaving good posts, voting for the good ones and awarding bounties to the truly great ones. This is a Question and Answer site, not a forum or social network.

So there you go, hope that was useful for you and you keep getting the most out of this site. It's quite a good site really, we're happy with it.

anyway, got to go now, it's getting late and this wine won't open itself.

TTFN,
Lots of love,

Jon
Stackexchange community moderator
June 2013

Comment: Thanks for that, now I have something to link to in my edit comment explaining the reason for the edit.

Comment: Awesome . . . .

Comment: Must... fight... urge... to... edit... out... stuff...

Comment: Why is Hobbes saying TTFN? I thought that was Tigger's phrase :P

Comment: @Manishearth: Well I thought that ending it with *"Don't Knock My Smock Or I'll Clean Your Clock"* was a bit too far.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends. I would expect most users of SE to be familiar with widespread 'Net memes, though granted these often have an English-speaking and Western bias. I often use **TL;DR** to preface my summary of the post. Perhaps I should use the word 'summary', but nobody's queried TL;DR to date, and I like it as it seems friendlier somehow. YMMV ;)